# initialize modelform fields with url parameters in cbv

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a cbv create view that displays a modelform.
I want to preselect a foreignkey field which is displayed as select choice field.
My problem is that kwargs.get('building_id') in modelform returns None

```
class VlanCreateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Vlan
        fields = ['number','description','network','building']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        building_id = kwargs.get('building_id')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
        self.fields['building'].initial = building_id
```

building is a foreign key to buildings. If I put a constant like self.fields['building'].initial = 1 it is working

```
class VlanCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Vlan
    form_class = VlanCreateForm
```

and the url is

```
vlan/building/<int:building_id>/create
```

so I call it like

```
vlan/building/1/create
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define the `building id` in [get_form_kwargs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs)

```py
class VlanCreateView(CreateView):
    ...
    building_id=None
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Retrieves the building id from url
        self.building_id=kwargs.get("building_id")
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs=super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        ## Sends building id to the form 
        kwargs["building_id"]=self.building_id
        return kwargs
```

Comment: Thank you Mugoma, I also needed to change get to pop otherwise my form complained about unexpected arguments (self.building_id = kwargs.pop('building_id'))

Answer (score 0):

```
class VlanCreateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Vlan
        fields = ['number','description','network','building']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.building_id = kwargs.get('building_id')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
        self.fields['building'].initial = self.building_id
  
   def post_url(self):
       return reverse('app_name:url_name',kwargs={'cg_id':self.building_id} )
```

In form post action use this post_url for submit form.
then you got the building_id in your view kwargs